# Is tomcat installed?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, tomcat

I have an `Ubuntu studio 16.10.`  I tried to install `tomcat 7` by using the command `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`.  I tried tomcat8 too, but after the following

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libtomcat8-java sysstat tomcat8-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libtomcat7-java tomcat7-common
Suggested packages:
  tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples tomcat7-user libtcnative-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtomcat7-java tomcat7 tomcat7-common
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 348 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,034 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,956 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 libtomcat7-java all 7.0.72-1 [3,730 kB]
Get:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 tomcat7-common all 7.0.72-1 [267 kB]
Get:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 tomcat7 all 7.0.72-1 [36.8 kB]
Fetched 4,034 kB in 4s (895 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtomcat7-java.
(Reading database ... 364399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libtomcat7-java_7.0.72-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtomcat7-java (7.0.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tomcat7-common.
Preparing to unpack .../1-tomcat7-common_7.0.72-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tomcat7-common (7.0.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tomcat7.
Preparing to unpack .../2-tomcat7_7.0.72-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tomcat7 (7.0.72-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libtomcat7-java (7.0.72-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (231-9ubuntu2) ...
Setting up tomcat7-common (7.0.72-1) ...
Setting up tomcat7 (7.0.72-1) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/tomcat7 with new version
Adding system user `tomcat7' (UID 126) ...
Adding new user `tomcat7' (UID 126) with group `tomcat7' ...
Not creating home directory `/usr/share/tomcat7'.

Creating config file /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7 with new version
Processing triggers for systemd (231-9ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
user@user:~$ tomcat --version
bash: tomcat: command not found
user@user:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/home/prasad/testfolder/
```

Tomcat, it seems has not been installed.  What do I do now?
Also I tried to remove tomcat and it prompted me for a a Yes/No and it went off fine.

Comment: If there're both tomcat7 and tomcat8 packages, perhaps they name the command the same way too

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s installed, and running — opening http://localhost:8080 will show you the default Tomcat welcome page. (At least, it will if you haven’t removed the package.)

You can install webapps by copying them to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`.

You won’t find a `tomcat` command, it’s installed as a service. Use `systemctl` to manage it.

Comment: where can I find the startup.sh as I just killed it. I tried find and locate find had too many answers

Comment: `systemctl status tomcat7` will display its current status. `systemctl start tomcat7` will start the tomcat  service